# Export to Excel from HTML table Jquery is not Exporting Headers of the Table

Tags: jquery, html, excel

I want to Export a HTML Table which is dynamically generated based on the data.
This is the table layout before the data is populated.
Once the data is queried, i'm populating the rows to the table dyanimcally.

```
<table id="findCntrctTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Contract <br />
                Number
            </th>
            <th>
                Requestor<br />
                Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Requesting<br />
                Office/District
            </th>
            <th>
                Requested<br />
                Date
            </th>
            <th>
                Contract<br />
                Status
            </th>
            <th>
                Estimated <br />
                Contract Cost
            </th>
            <th>
                Contract <br />
                Type
            </th>
            <th>
                Receivable/
                <br />Payable
            </th>
            <th>
                Contractors
                <br />
            </th>
            <th>
                SP Numbers
                <br />
            </th>    
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have link to export the table to Excel

```
<a href="#" style="cursor: pointer; font-weight:bold; font-style:italic; float:right " onclick=ExportToExcel()>Export to Excel</a>
```

here's the jquery Function i wrote

```
function ExportToExcel() {
    debugger;
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel';
    var table = $('#findCntrctTable');
    //var Header = table.find('th');
    var table_html = table[0].outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');
    a.href = data_type + ', ' + table_html;
    a.download = 'SearchResults.xls';
    a.click();
    //window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(table[0].outerHTML));
 }
```

This is how my table is being populated once i get the data

```
    function writetable(data) {         
        var tableOutline = '';          
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var id = 'row' + data[i].ContractNumber;
        tableOutline = tableOutline + '<tr id="row_' + data[i].ContractNumber + '" onclick="getCntrctNbr(this,' + data[i].ContractNumber + ')"><td style="text-align:left" ><a>';
        tableOutline = tableOutline + data[i].ContractNumber + '</a></td><td>' + data[i].RequestorName + '</td><td>' + data[i].RequestingOffDisct + '</td><td style="text-align:right">' + formatJSONDate(data[i].RequestedDate) + '</td><td>' + data[i].ContractStatus + '</td><td style="text-align:right">' + formatCurrency(data[i].EstimateContractCost) + '</td><td>' + data[i].ContractType + '</td><td>' + data[i].PayReceivable + '</td><td>' + data[i].ControrList + '</td><td>' + data[i].SPList + '</td></tr>';
        }
            tableOutline = tableOutline;
            $('#findCntrctTable').append(tableOutline);
            $('#findCntrctTable').show();

        }
```

When export to excel the header fields are not showing up in the spreadsheet.
Can You please Help me with this issue.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow there are 2 tables created one for the headers and one for the rows with data. that's the reason the outerhtml of table findCntrctTable doesn't have any headers in it.

I have manually added the headers here's the code

```
 $('#exportToExcel').on('click', function () {
        debugger;
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel';
        var table = $('#findCntrctTable');
        // var Header = table.find('th');
        var table_html = '<table> <thead><tr><th>Contract Number</th><th>Requestor Name</th><th>Requesting Office/District</th><th>Requested Date</th><th>Contract Status</th><th>Estimated Contract Cost</th><th>Contract Type</th><th>Receivable/Payable</th><th>Contractors</th><th>SP Numbers</th></tr></thead></table>';
        table_html = table_html + table[0].outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');
        a.href = data_type + ', ' + table_html;
        a.download = 'MnDOTContractsList.xls';
        a.click();
       // window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(table[0].outerHTML));
    });
```

This works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with the code a bit I came up with the following:

```
<table id="findCntrctTable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Contract
            <br />Number</th>
        <th>Requestor
            <br />Name</th>
        <th>Requesting
            <br />Office/District</th>
        <th>Requested
            <br />Date</th>
        <th>Contract
            <br />Status</th>
        <th>Estimated
            <br />Contract Cost</th>
        <th>Contract
            <br />Type</th>
        <th>Receivable/
            <br />Payable</th>
        <th>Contractors
            <br />
        </th>
        <th>SP Numbers
            <br />
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr></tr>
</tbody>
```

```
 <a id="exportToExcel" href="#" style="cursor: pointer; font-weight:bold; font-style:italic; float:right">Export to Excel</a>

 $('#exportToExcel').on('click', function() {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel';
    var table = $('#findCntrctTable');
    var Header = table.find('th');
    var table_html = table[0].outerHTML.replace(/" "/g, '%20');

    a.href = data_type + ', ' + table_html;
    a.download = 'SearchResults.xls';
    a.click();
    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(table[0].outerHTML));
});
```

Granted there is some ugly formatting in the html but I was able to export the table headers.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hm2jv77L/8/)

Comment: I implemented this code, and it still doesn't download with headers and also, the file doesnt load with the extension .xls

Comment: @CoderUnknown I removed the `onClick` from the link and gave it an Id. Then I altered your function code to add an `on.('click'` function for the link. When I run the JsFiddle code I am able to view the headers in Excel 10. I had to edit the link I provided, I had made an update just before posting and had the wrong link.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to put that code in my application, will test it out and let you know.

Comment: I'm  Really confused!! Iam using the same code used in the JSFiddle in my application.(table[0].outerHTML) yields different values..In the Fiddle (table[0].outerHTML) gets the headers, but not in my application. I have no clue Y

Comment: @CoderUnknown Can you post some more of your source code in an edit?

Comment: For the code you have provided table.find('th') gives u 10 rows, for my table it gives 0 rows.